# Which unicode character can be used as a pictogram for a QR code?

Tags: unicode, character, special-characters, qr-code

I wonder if there is a Unicode character symbolizing a QR code?

I think I have seen that some time ago as an character but I can't remember if it was a custom font or an official Unicode character.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you mean a unicode character. There is no such thing like a utf-8 character. You can encode a character in utf-8. I never heard about that unicode codepoints cover qr codes. With private codepoints as well as the appropriate font it's of course possible.

Comment: I think we have some unicode codepoints suitable for qr codes.

Comment: I think the question was which Unicode symbol to use to display a QR code. And this is possibly a question for programmers after all, because you may want to use the symbol in error messages or log entries, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Try install qrencode (https://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en)

```
qrencode -t UTF8 -o file "José João Dias de Almeida"
```

makes a textual file "file" (17 lines):

```
█████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▀█ █▄█▀▀▄█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ████
████ █   █ █▀▀▀█ ▀▀ ██ █   █ ████
████ █▄▄▄█ █▀ █▀▀█▀▀▀█ █▄▄▄█ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄▀ ▀▄█ █▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄████
████ ▄ ▄ █▄▄ ▄▀▄ ▄█▄ ▄█▄▀ █ █████
████   ▀▄▀▄█▀█▄█▀██ ▄▀▄▄▄█  ▄████
████ ▄█▄▄ ▄▀█▄▄▀▄█▄▄▀▄▄▀▀ █▄█████
████ █ █ ▄▄▄██ █▄█▀ ▄ █  ▀ ▄▄████
████▄███▄▄▄█▀▀▄▀▄ ▄▀ ▄▄▄   █▀████
████ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄███▀█▄█ █▄█ ▀█ ▄████
████ █   █ █ ▀  ▄ ▄ ▄▄ ▄  ▄▀▀████
████ █▄▄▄█ █ ▄ ███ ▀██▀▄▀▄██ ████
████▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄███▄▄▄███▄█▄▄█▄▄████
█████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████



$ wc -l file
17
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the *Tetragram for stoppage*, , Unicode U+1D34C, hexadecimal: 0x1d34c in block [Tai Xuan Jing Symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/tai-xuan-jing-symbols/).
Maybe you prefer another Tai Xuan Jing symbol, there are several to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing official, but `U+25A3 WHITE SQUARE CONTAINING BLACK SMALL SQUARE` ▣ might be good enough for some use cases.